# convert DateTimeindex to contain only year, hour and day not time information

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with an index that also contains the Hour:second:... but instead I just want it to contain the date as year, month, day.

Is it possible for the index to still be a DateTimeIndex but contain only year, month, day?

The current index looks like:

```
my_index = DatetimeIndex(['2017-08-25', '2017-08-24', '2017-08-23', '2017-08-22',
           '2017-08-21', '2017-08-20', '2017-08-19', '2017-08-18',
           '2017-08-17', '2017-08-16',
           ...
           '2015-07-19', '2015-07-18', '2015-07-17', '2015-07-16',
           '2015-07-15', '2015-07-14', '2015-07-13', '2015-07-12',
           '2015-07-11', '2015-07-10'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=778, freq=None)
```

I could do:

```
only_date_index = [el.date() for el in my_index]
```

But then if I want to use the resample function in pandas I get the error:
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'.

Comment: Try `.normalize()` it will make the times go to midnight, as i believe the `DateTimeIndex` needs the time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need [`DatetimeIndex.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html):

```
myIndex = df.index.floor('D')
```

Sample:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03 15:00:45', periods=10, freq='24T')
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10)}, index=rng)  
print (df)
                     a
2017-04-03 15:00:45  0
2017-04-03 15:24:45  1
2017-04-03 15:48:45  2
2017-04-03 16:12:45  3
2017-04-03 16:36:45  4
2017-04-03 17:00:45  5
2017-04-03 17:24:45  6
2017-04-03 17:48:45  7
2017-04-03 18:12:45  8
2017-04-03 18:36:45  9

myIndex = df.index.floor('D')
print (myIndex)
DatetimeIndex(['2017-04-03', '2017-04-03', '2017-04-03', '2017-04-03',
               '2017-04-03', '2017-04-03', '2017-04-03', '2017-04-03',
               '2017-04-03', '2017-04-03'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Thanks for another solution [Deckerz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45943321/convert-datetimeindex-to-contain-only-year-hour-and-day-not-time-information/45943387#comment78845008_45943387) - using [`DatetimeIndex.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.normalize.html):

```
myIndex = df.index.normalize()
print (myIndex)
DatetimeIndex(['2017-04-03', '2017-04-03', '2017-04-03', '2017-04-03',
               '2017-04-03', '2017-04-03', '2017-04-03', '2017-04-03',
               '2017-04-03', '2017-04-03'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

**Timings**:

```
ix = pd.date_range('1970-01-01', '2200-01-15', freq='1H')

print (len(ix))
2016481

In [68]: %timeit (ix.normalize())
10 loops, best of 3: 178 ms per loop

In [69]: %timeit (ix.floor('d'))
10 loops, best of 3: 38.4 ms per loop

#solution from Dror (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954497/in-pandas-group-by-date-from-datetimeindex)
In [70]: %timeit pd.to_datetime(ix.date)
1 loop, best of 3: 5.09 s per loop
```

Comment: `.normalize()` also does this and is an embedded function for DateTimeIndex arrays but not single instances