# Pandas: Accessing data with list of dates and DateTimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetimeindex

I have a pandas DataFrame with a `DateTimeIndex`:

```
                           A          B
2016-04-25 18:50:06   440.967796   201.049600  
2016-04-25 18:50:13   441.054995   200.767034  
2016-04-25 18:50:20   441.142337   200.484475
...
2016-07-27 18:50:06   440.967796   201.049600  
2016-07-27 18:50:13   441.054995   200.767034  
2016-07-27 18:50:20   441.142337   200.484475
```

I would like to extract all the data of a given date `yyyy-mm-dd` using a list of dates: `['2016-04-25','2016-04-28',...]`

I tried the following:

```
 df[df.index.isin(['2016-04-25', '2016-04-26'])]

 Empty DataFrame
```

I would like to retrieve all the data (data of the whole day) of the dates given in this list

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need remove times first by [this solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45943387/2901002):

```
df = df[df.index.normalize().isin(['2016-04-25', '2016-04-26'])]
```

---

```
df = df[df.index.floor('D').isin(['2016-04-25', '2016-04-26'])]
```

Another solution is compare [`DatetimeIndex.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html), but necessary use [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) instead `isin`:

```
df = df[np.in1d(df.index.date, pd.to_datetime(['2016-04-25', '2016-04-26']).date)]
```

Or compare strings created [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
df = df[np.in1d(df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), ['2016-04-25', '2016-04-26'])]
```

---

```
print (df)
                              A           B
2016-04-25 18:50:06  440.967796  201.049600
2016-04-25 18:50:13  441.054995  200.767034
2016-04-25 18:50:20  441.142337  200.484475
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a follow up question. Is it possible to cut off the first `n` data rows in each individual day, without copying any data? The days have different start/end times and different numbers of data rows

Comment: Hmmm, try `df = df.drop(df.groupby(df.index.date).head(2).index)` - it remove first 2 value from each date.